# Is there a punishment for someone who asks a woman to divorce her husband for no valid reason?

Tags: sharia, punishment, talaq

If someone/woman gives an advice(with a bad intention) to a woman to divorce her husband (for simple/non-valid reasons), What would be his/her punishment in the hereafter according to the Quran and Sunnah?

Comment: This could fall under deception.

Answer (score 1):

There is no worldly punishment indicated through as appears in my research. Though, the issue is mentioned quite a lot specially from family members pressing their son or daughter to divorce the other.

In one of the questions asked to *islamweb.net*, the answer was that it is a major sin to do it. The one asking was telling that he felt in love with a married women and made a promise with her to marry her when she is divorced from his husband who, as the one asking said, was doing many haram things.

Source: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/130035

In addition, what this woman is doing is a manifestation of *fasad* (corruption), and Allah does not like corrupters.

> And they strive throughout the land [causing] corruption, and Allah does not like corrupters. [Quran](http://quran.com/5/64)

### Opinion

I just cannot understand why one would feel to ask such a question. I mean, really, we know from our tradition about the women who was a devout worshiper but did not feed nor let the cat feed from the worms of the ground, and thus is in the hellfire regardless of what she did good.

Something I feel sad about is that some Muslims feel that they are on contract with Allah, so if something bad seems *not important* or *little* people will do it because they will still *pass* to paradise. We forgot what Omar ibn Al-Khattab said once, that even if one of his legs is in the paradise, he is not sure that the latter will make it there too.

You can be a devout worshiper, but because of small thing you go to hellfire, while one might enter paradise with so many sins because of some sincere doings.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no specific punishment mentioned in the Quran nor sunnah for someone who does that. Only Allah knows. However, this is not permissible in Islam and if someone does it, it will be counted as a sin which might lead him/her to be punished in hell (if bad deeds are more than good deeds)

Comment: about 'might lead him/her to be punished in hell (if bad deeds are more than good deeds)': Does not Islam says that if you violate some human right(Huqooq ul Ibad) then only that human can forgive you for that. So, I think no matter how many good deeds you did, you'll still be answerable for  harming other people.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no specific punishment for such a matter. Seemingly, it has not narrated directly regarding this matter, but the significant point is that God himself will definitely punish her (in this world or on the Day of judgement).